# KeyValuePair with repeated Keys

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am making a LINQ query to obtain all values in 2 fields from a database, age and date. I want to display the 5 highest age figures on a chart. To do so, I was trying to store the age and date in 2 separate Lists, ageList and dateList.

Initially when comparing the value against index to index in each List, the relation to the age and date would be correct. For example:

age stored at ageList.ElementAt(0) would be the correct value for the date at dateList.ElementAt(0).

But since I am going to get the 5 highest age figures, I would need to **Sort** the ageList list. By doing that I am going to lose the match between the 2 lists.

I tried to store the data in a SortedDictionary instead where the Key is age and Value is date. Problem is it doesn't allow repeated Keys. In my case, I would need repeated keys since multiple age can be the same and date can be the same too.

Is there any way around this?

My code trying to store with a Dictionary. It would throw an exception when it is storing repeated Keys.

```
//Linq query
var xChartData = from x in db.Person
                 select new { x.Age, x.Date };

SortedDictionary<double, DateTime> topAgeDict = new SortedDictionary<double, DateTime>();

//Storing in Dictionary
foreach (var x in xChartData)
{
    topAgeDict.Add(x.Age, x.Date); //Exception caused when repeated values
}

Dictionary<string, string> stringDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//store data as string for chart purposes
foreach (var x in topAgeDict)
{
    stringDict.Add(x.Key.ToString(), x.Value.ToString());  
}

List<string> ages = new List<string>();
List<string> dates = new List<string>();

//storing the dictionary key and value in List for element access.
ages = stringDict.Keys.ToList();
dates = stringDict.Values.ToList();

//to store only the top 5 results. This will be the data used in chart.
List<string> topFiveAge = new List<string>();
List<string> topFiveDate = new List<string>();

for (int x=1; x <= 5; x++)
{
    topFiveAge.Add(ages.ElementAt(ages.Count - x));
    topFiveDate.Add(dates.ElementAt(dates.Count - x));
}

//Chart
var topAgefilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Chart_Files/topAge.jpg");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(topAgefilePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(topAgefilePath);
            }
            var ageChart = new Chart(580, 400);
            ageChart.AddTitle("Top Age");
            ageChart.AddSeries(
                chartType: "column",
                xValue: topFiveDate,
                yValues: topFiveAge
            );
            ageChart.Save(topAgefilePath);
```

Comment: First of all, ages are numbers: don't store them as `string`s. Depending on what you want to do, you can either choose to use a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` which, when properly sorted, will give you the five oldest users, possibly all with the same age. Or, you can use a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` to store a list of all users with a certain age indexed by age. Or, if you are only interested in the maximum, just copy your age list, sort it and take the top 5 elements.

Comment: what in the world is `Date` supposed to be here.. ? i.e. `CreatedDate`, `ModifiedDate`, `BirthDate` ??

Comment: I mean.. it doesn't really matter, but it's kind of improper since it's coming from a dbcontext (presumably)..

Comment: in reference to my comment on my answer, is `xValue` supposed to be a collection or a singular instance?

Comment: @BrettCaswell xValue is a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// top 5 oldest persons
var xChartData = (from x in db.Person
                 order by x.Age descending                 
                 select new { x.Age, x.Date })
                 .Take (5);
```

And I see no real reason to split that into two `List<>`s

Comment: Yet to test but this Linq query makes sense and able to avoid the multiple Lists I am creating. But I believe I would still need 2 separate lists for the chart to be able to place them for the x and y values. I have updated the code section to show my chart codes.

Comment: The linq query will be essential when you have very many Persons. And I don't know what Char library this is but I'm sure it accepts DateTime and int or double as values. It does look like you have to split it for this call. Doesn't it provide its own x,y datatype?

Answer (score 2):

You should really create concrete types, since you'll be providing that type to a control of some sort.

```
public class PersonAgeDateItem
{
    public string Age {get;set;} // should be an int though..
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

Lambda version of getting the data;

Note that I'm using anonymous `object` instances here and then doing a `Select` to `PersonAgeDateItem` later. This implementation doesn't benefit from having anonymous object instances, but there are some benefit considerations in the form of object comparison (in lieu of implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` on `PersonAgeDateItem`, `overriding` `GetHashCode` and `Object.Equals`), if you end up adding `GroupBy` `Distinct`... or any scenario like that...

```
var data = db.Person.Select(person => new { Age = person.Age, Date = person.Date })
                    .OrderByDescending(person => person.Age)
                    .Take(5)
                    .Select(person => new PersonAgeDateItem() {
                        Age = person.Age,
                        Date = person.Date
                    });
// person.Age, being a string, could pose an issue.. like "2" coming after "19", "199", "1999".. etc etc
```

Then we perform another `Select` for the `xValue`, `yValue` initializations.

```
...
ageChart.AddSeries( 
    chartType: "column", 
    xValue: data.Select(person => person.Age), 
    yValues: data.Select(person => person.Date));
```

Comment: is `xValue` supposed to be singular?... hmm.. the chart is probably going to be inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `Dictionary`, you can use a `List<Tuple<double, DateTime>>` to hold your list of age and date.

```
var ageAndDate = from x in db.Person
                    select new Tuple<double, DateTime>(x.Age, x.Date);

var topFiveAgeWithdate = ageAndDate.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item1).Take(5).ToList();

List<string> topFiveAge = topFiveAgeWithdate.Select(t => t.Item1.ToString()).ToList();
List<string> topFiveDate = topFiveAgeWithdate.Select(t => t.Item2.ToShortDateString()).ToList();
```

Same can be done with `Anonymous Type`s

```
var ageAndDate = from x in persons
                    select new { x.Age, x.Date };

var topFiveAgeWithdate = ageAndDate.OrderByDescending(t => t.Age).Take(5).ToList();

List<string> topFiveAge = topFiveAgeWithdate.Select(t => t.Age.ToString()).ToList();
List<string> topFiveDate = topFiveAgeWithdate.Select(t => t.Date.ToShortDateString()).ToList();
```